# Can i paint over this semi sanded gloss door?

Tags: wood, doors, paint, paint-removal, oil-based-paint

The door has been painted with white oil-based wood gloss paint over the past 15-20 years (See first image). In the past, I would just paint over it which worked fine the few times I did it.

Now I want to switch from gloss to satinwood paint, I've brought [Dulux trade satinwood white](https://www.screwfix.com/p/dulux-trade-satinwood-paint-pure-brilliant-white-2-5ltr/12367). From my research, I understand it's not possible to just paint on top of the current gloss paint so I started to sand down the door. See before and after image:
[image: Before sanding down]
[image: After sanding down]

- Do I need to sand the door down 100% where the is no paint left?
- Can I just sand down the first layer so the gloss paint is semi removed and then paint over it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I just sand down the first layer so the gloss paint is semi removed and then paint over it?

**YES** - there is no need to sand all the way *through* the existing paint. You just need to de-gloss the paint and the new paint should stick fine.

Concern- the fact that you repainted previously, without sanding, may cause one or more layers of old paint to start to peel up. This is a problem that would require more thorough sanding. In fact, you would need to sand off all paint that appears to be peeling.